# Bootstrap forms to HeidiSQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Can you give me some tips with this. I made a form with bootstrap and I don't know how to make this: when I complete all steps (firstname, secondname, email, password, gender, status(student/professor)) and press submit to save this information into my database (I use HeidiSQL).

```
<div class="container">
<h2> Completati formularul</h2>
<form role="form">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="prenume">Prenume</label>
        <input type="prenume" class="form-control" id="prenume" placeholder="Enter prenume"></input>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name"></input>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="cnp">CNP</label>
        <input type="cnp" class="form-control" id="cnp" placeholder="Enter the cnp"></input>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">E-mail</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter E-mail"></input>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Parola</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter password"></input>
    </div>

    <p>Sex</p>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="m">Masculin</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="f">Feminin</label>
        </div>


    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Statut
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
             <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li> </li>
                <li><a href="#">Student</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Profesor</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Suport tehnic</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <p>Necesar</p>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Videoproiector</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Flipchart</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Marker</label>
        </div>

    <p>Observatii</p>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with PHP; it is possible to submit your form back to the same PHP Script where the form lives. Assuming that the File where the HTML Form lives is called index.php, You could do something like this:

**PHP PART OF YOUR index.php FILE**

```
    <?php
        // FILENAME: index.php

        // THIS CODE BELOW IS BEST PLACED AT THE VERY TOP OF THE FILE BEFORE THE OPENING <HTML> TAG
        // GET THE POSTED FORM-DATA AND SANITIZE THEM A BIT:
        $prenume    = isset($_POST['prenume'])      ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['prenume']))     :null;
        $name       = isset($_POST['name'])         ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['name']))        :null;
        $cnp        = isset($_POST['cnp'])          ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['cnp']))         :null;
        $email      = isset($_POST['email'])        ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['email']))       :null;
        $password   = isset($_POST['password'])     ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['password']))    :null;
        $sex        = isset($_POST['sex'])          ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['sex']))         :null;
        $message    = isset($_POST['message'])      ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['message']))     :null;
        $statut     = isset($_POST['statut'])       ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['statut']))      :null;
        $necessar   = isset($_POST['necessar'])     ? $_POST['necessar']                            :array();


        $arrData    = array(
            "prenume"   => $prenume,
            "name"      => $name,
            "cnp"       => $cnp,
            "email"     => $email,
            "password"  => $password,
            "sex"       => $sex,
            "message"   => $message,
            "statut"    => $statut,
            "necessar"  => $necessar,
        );

        $errorCss   = array(
            "prenume"   => "",
            "name"      => "",
            "cnp"       => "",
            "email"     => "",
            "password"  => "",
            "sex"       => "",
            "message"   => "",
            "statut"    => "",
            "necessar"  => "",
        );

        // CREATE A VARIABLE TO HOLD THE ERROR MESSAGES (IN CASE THERE IS ONE...
        $arrErrors  = array();
        $strErrMsg  = "";
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            foreach($arrData as $fldName=>$fldVal){
                if(!$fldVal || empty($fldVal)){
                    $arrErrors[] = "The Field \"" . ucfirst($fldName) . "\" should not be empty. Please, fill it.";
                    $errorCss[$fldName] = "has-error";
                }
            }
        }

        // IF OUR ERRORS ARRAY IS EMPTY, SIMPLY SEND SAVE THE DATA
        // OTHERWISE DISPLAY THE ERROR STRING TO THE USER TO LET THEM KNOW WHAT HAS HAPPENED
        if(!empty($arrErrors)){
            $strErrMsg  = implode("<br />", $arrErrors);
        }else{
            // THIS IS WHERE AND WHEN YOU INSERT YOUR DATA INTO THE DATABASE...

            // RESET ALL FORM-FIELDS TO NULL...
            $prenume    = "";
            $name       = "";
            $cnp        = "";
            $email      = "";
            $password   = "";
            $sex        = "";
            $message    = "";
            $statut     = "";
            $necessar   = array();
        }

    ?>
```

**HTML PART OF YOUR index.php FILE**

```
    <!-- FILENAME: index.php -->
    <!-- ADD A CSS STYLE TO HIGHLIGHT ERRORS-->
    <style type="text/css">
        .has-error{
            border:  solid #FF0000 1px;
        }
    </style>

    <div class="container">
        <h2> Completati formularul</h2>
        <!-- CREATE A DIV TO HOLD YOUR ERROR MESSAGES -->
        <div class="error-message"><?php echo $strErrMsg; ?></div>

        <form role="form" method="POST" action="">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="prenume">Prenume</label>
                    <input type="text" name="prenume" class="form-control <?php echo $errorCss["prenume"];?>" id="prenume" placeholder="Enter prenume" value="<?php echo $prenume; ?>" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control <?php echo $errorCss["name"];?>" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cnp">CNP</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cnp" class="form-control <?php echo $errorCss["cnp"];?>" id="cnp" placeholder="Enter the cnp" value="<?php echo $cnp; ?>" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">E-mail</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control <?php echo $errorCss["email"];?>" id="email" placeholder="Enter E-mail" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Parola</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control <?php echo $errorCss["password"];?>" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password" value="<?php echo $password; ?>" />
                </div>

                <p>Sex</p>
                <div class="radio <?php echo $errorCss["sex"];?>">
                    <label><input type="radio" value="m" <?php if($sex == "m"){echo "checked";} ?> name="sex" />Masculin</label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio <?php echo $errorCss["sex"];?>">
                    <label><input type="radio" value="f" name="sex" <?php if($sex == "f"){echo "checked";} ?> />Feminin</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="statut">Statut</label>
                    <select class="form-control <?php echo $errorCss["statut"];?>" id="statut" name="statut" >
                        <option value="" <?php if($statut == ""){echo "selected";} ?> >Please chose your Status</option>
                        <option value="Student" <?php if($statut == "Student"){echo "selected";} ?> >Student</option>
                        <option value="Profesor" <?php if($statut == "Profesor"){echo "selected";} ?> >Profesor</option>
                        <option value="Suport tehnic" <?php if($statut == "Suport tehnic"){echo "selected";} ?> >Suport tehnic</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <br/>
                <p>Necesar</p>
                <div class="checkbox <?php echo $errorCss["necessar"];?>">
                    <label for="Videoproiector">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="Videoproiector" name="necessar[]" value="Videoproiector" <?php if(in_array("Videoproiector", $necessar)){echo "checked";} ?> />Videoproiector
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="checkbox <?php echo $errorCss["necessar"];?>">
                    <label for="Flipchart">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="Flipchart" name="necessar[]" value="Flipchart" <?php if(in_array("Flipchart", $necessar)){echo "checked";} ?> />Flipchart
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="checkbox <?php echo $errorCss["necessar"];?>">
                    <label for="Marker">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="Marker" name="necessar[]" value="Marker" <?php if(in_array("Marker", $necessar)){echo "checked";} ?> />Marker
                    </label>
                </div>

                <p>Observatii</p>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control <?php echo $errorCss["message"];?>" name="message" placeholder="Message"><?php echo $message; ?></textarea>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```